# i am looking for an alternative to the php-info file as the server i am on will not allow it to run, is there any alternate code i can use?

Tags: ssh, php

currently on the server a large amount of php scripts have been locked out is there any alternative to the phpinfo file that would be able to run as html or be able to pull php info through command line/ SSH  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what you're looking for, you can see the values for any of the [superglobals](https://www.php.net/language.variables.superglobals)

eg: $_SERVER

```
<h2>Server: </h2>
<?php
echo "<pre>".print_r($_SERVER,1)."</pre>";
?>
```

For the ini_$ values, you can use [ini_get_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php):

```
<h2>ini presets: </h2>
<?php
echo "<pre>".print_r(ini_get_all(),1)."</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "phpinfo file" you're describing is almost certainly just calling the PHP's built in [`phpinfo()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) that renders PHP's configuration as an HTML table.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

renders this:

[image]

From the command line, you can also run the following command to get PHP's configuration:

```
$ php -i
```